# FindViewbyId always returns Null in Fragment

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments, findviewbyid

I have an xml file as shown below:

**One.xml**

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/additemsbackground"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp">
  <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/btnaddtxt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@drawable/add" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

This is my MainFragment:

```
  @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this);
       View myView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.One,
            null);
       ImageView btnadd=(ImageView)myView.findViewById(R.id.btnaddtxt);
       btnadd.setOnClickListener(
        new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                              "Clicked Add Text Button" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                              .show();
                }
            });
  }
```

When I'm trying to get the `ImageView` as shown in my `MainFragment` it always returns null.

Can anyone say me what's the correct way of doing this ?

Comment: do you have the Fragment as inner class for your activity ?

Comment: @Blackbelt-Yes...I have

Comment: the fragment should be static then. Afterwards you will get some compile-time errors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Initialize your views in onCreateView(...) and not in onCreate(...) when using Fragments. Something like this

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.delivery_boys, container,
                false);
        ImageView btnadd=(ImageView)rootView .findViewById(R.id.btnaddtxt);

        return rootView;
    }
```

Comment: Yes. We did it at same time. And I don't know who downvoted you and why :)

Answer (score 0):

you are suppose to inflate view in onCreateView in your fragment class

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.delivery_boys, container,
                false);
        ImageView img=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.your_img_view);

        return view;
    }
```

`onCreateView` function you get attached to the activity and you get you get view inflation opportunity in `onCreate` Method Fragment is initialized and not yet attached to activity.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public View setContentView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (mChangeVehiclesView == null) {
        mChangeVehiclesView = inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.frag_vehicles_registered, null);
    } else {
        ((ViewGroup) mChangeVehiclesView.getParent())
                .removeView(mChangeVehiclesView);
    }
mvehicleListView = (ListView) mChangeVehiclesView
            .findViewById(R.id.frag_vehicle_registeres_list);
    return mChangeVehiclesView;
}
```

Comment: mChangeVehiclesView is the View you want to return and mvehicleListView  is the widget.